# Router scope messes up url builder

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.0

In my app I defined a scope for API calls.

```php
Router::scope('/api', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->setExtensions(['json']);
    $routes->resources('Invoices');
});
```

I want to serve `/api/invoices` and `/invoices` from the same controller method.

In my `default.ctp` layout I have the following link.

```php
<?= $this->Html->link(
   '<i class="fi-book"> ' . __('Invoices') . '</i>',
   [
      'plugin' => false,
      'prefix' => false,
      'controller' => 'invoices',
      'action' => 'index'
   ],
   ['escape' => false]
) ?>
```

And it gives me `/api/invoices`, what is wrong as I would not need `/api` prefix here.

However the next link is:

```php
<?= $this->Html->link(
   '<i class="fi-plus"> ' . __('New Invoice') . '</i>',
   [
      'plugin' => false,
      'prefix' => false,
      'controller' => 'invoices',
      'action' => 'add'
   ],
   ['escape' => false]
) ?>
```

generates `/invoices/add`. There is now `/api` prefix what is the desired behaviour.

What do I miss?

Comment: Whenever you have routing problems, check what routes are connected in which order using the routes shell: `bin/cake routes`. It will also show you which arguments you have to supply to generate a specific URL and which names you could use. That being said, you're probably better off using a prefix here, as a scope cannot be explicitly targeted when generating URLs.

Comment: @ndm but if I use a prefix than I have to cretae a dedicated controller, right?

Comment: Yes. That controller could of course for example extend a base controller if you're worried about code duplication. And there's certainly other ways to handle this too, like maybe named routes, or custom routing parameters. It's really hard to tell what might be the best way to solve this without knowing about all your other routes, and your app in general.